# Vertical centering of div without Javascript when div's height isn't fixed

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertical center a `div` without JavaScript when **its height isn't fixed**.

I found [here](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) one idea.

I wonder if there are other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

Here's link: http://jsbin.com/uvodop/2/edit

See how it's vertically aligned within the box. Height as well isn't fixed.

Hope it answers your question.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Div vertical align using CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outerDiv {
            border: solid 1px #000000;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
        }

        .innerDiv {
            width: 95%;
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 40px 0px 40px 5px;
            border: solid 1px #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outerDiv">
        <div class="innerDiv">
            This text is placed inside the next HTML div tag.<br />
            CSS style is used to vertical align the nested div and text.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the height of the outerDiv is fixed, say 700px.

Comment: well I fixed it... if you want it to dynamically change I think you might need JavaScript... http://jsbin.com/uvodop/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old thread, I think this answer might help someone. If the version of IE is flexible to at least IE > 8, then you can use `display:table-cell` and use the default `vertical-align` feature.

In the code below, the `div.hover` which is the div that is going to be vertically aligned middle is not assigned any height however the parent(s) are assigned 100% height to fill the screen.

Check this out

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: table;
}
.inner {
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.hover {
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="hover">
        I am a random text to give the div some height
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```