# Vertically align middle without knowing the height

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="grid-960">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col col-6-12">
            <img src="imgs/image.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-6-12 last">
            <h2>Title1</h2>
            <p>My content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem:

Yes I know how to vertically align most content. I've used many techniques, for example setting the parent as table and the child as table-cell. However most techniques requires me to either know the height of the parent/child - or they assume you are working with a block element.

I am working with a floated element, and I don't know the height of it(dynamic content).

```
.col{float:left}
```

Basically I need the elements on the right col vertically align with the image on the left.
Because my columns float left, 100% height will have no effect.

Any ideas?

*By the way, I am not sure why my code never display's correctly here. I can't seem to get the indents to work.

Comment: You don't need to keep it as float:left, do you?  Why not remove the float and do it as a table-cell structure?

Comment: But you don't need a fixed height with display: table / cell. Also this seems to be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412912/align-vertically-using-css-3

Comment: @andi - Yes I need to keep it as float, for responsive design purpose. It's a grid.

Comment: @onetrickpony - because the col div is floated, the height of the element will be as tall as itself, therefore, it won't stretch to the height of it's parent.

Comment: @gdaniel - I am pretty sure this cannot be done with pure CSS, unless you remove the float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    // VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION
    $.fn.vAlign = function() {
        return this.each(function(i){
            var ah = $(this).height();
            var ph = $(this).parent().height();
            var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
            $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
        });
   };
})(jQuery);

$('.classname').vAlign();
```

Source: http://atomiku.com/2012/02/simple-jquery-plugin-for-vertically-centering/

**UPDATE**

Possible CSS solution: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUdKD/)**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam blanditiis optio aliquam voluptas adipisci itaque repellendus voluptatum magni vel nam sequi hic voluptatem perferendis deleniti labore aliquid incidunt officiis magnam.</div>
</div>

.parent {
    width:300px;
    padding:50% 0;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.child {
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: @Shivam... I know how to achieve this with jquery. I just really wanted to achieve this with css. Thanks though!

Comment: @gdaniel take a look at this, maybe it might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997500/vertical-centering-of-div-without-javascript-when-divs-height-isnt-fixed

Comment: the example you linked above, only works because they have the parent height set. Thanks for your help though. I think I will resort to jquery.

Comment: Try removing the `set height` from `parent div` and set a `padding-top` & `padding-bottom` to 50%. Example: http://jsbin.com/uvodop/22/edit

Comment: Adding equal padding works most of the time, depending on the height of the parent. But I think I will use this, since my parents div will mostly have the same height (even though it's not explicitly set). You can either update your answer, or post a new one and I will close it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully this could be some what helpful :). Its difficult to really only use CSS to vertical align a div unless using table-cell etc... but yeah, good luck on your project!

Answer (score 4):

You could still use `vertical-align: middle` and `display: table-cell` if you wrap your `.col`s within [two DIVs that use table display mode](http://jsfiddle.net/aK695/).

```
.wrap-1{
  display: table;
  min-height: 100%;   /* extend table height to min. 100% of the floated elm. */
}

.wrap-2{
  display: table-row;
}

.col{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And another way, [using flexboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xpns/):

```
.row{
  float:left; 

  display: -webkit-flex;    
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-align-items: center;    
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;   
}
```